# timed loop to retrieve gps co-ordinates and eventually calculate speed

Tags: android, performance, geolocation, gps, position

***   UPDATED AT THE BOTTOM   ***

Basically, I'm trying to write a simple app to locate where I am and update my position every [ fixed time interval ]

I followed [this](http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2007/12/cruising-around-with-android.html) tutorial and managed to obtain a value my position. However, for the life of me I cannot get it to work in an endless loop. I just want it to keep going until I quit the application (by pressing the back button for the time being).

The reason I want to have a loop like this is because I want to calculate my speed. I was going to do it like this:

```
loop{

   get Location and store it
   wait One Second
   get Location and store it
   wait One Second
   get Location and store it
   wait One Second
   get Location and store it
   wait One Second
   get Location and store it
   wait One Second

   calculate distance traveled and divide by 5 to get average speed
   print latest location and speed

}
```

Now, this is just the VERY basic version of what I would like to do. Idealy I would like to have a thread handle the timer and another get the locations (to ensure that the location is taken PRECISELY on one second intervals by locking the other thread out of getting the location until "timer % 1000 milliseconds == 0" or something like that), then have another thread for the computation of current speed.

I am new at android programming however, so I'm not sure if im going in the right direction to do this, or even if this is the correct way to go about solving this problem, I'm not necessarily looking for the code, but if you guys could help me in the right direction, suggest how to obtain the data in a more accurate/efficent way, or even suggestions about how I should change the logic of my code that would be great!... BUUUUT if you DO want to help me out with some code I would be very thankful! :D

Also, I was wondering if this might be a better way to calculate the speed, would I get a more accurate reading if I, say:

```
get location
add to arrayList

...fill list with 5 items and enter loop of...

calculate speed with items from list  <---
                                         |
remove oldest item from list             |
add current location to list             |
                                         |
loop -------------------------------------
```

this way I could have a new speed value every second, but still have the accuracy of calculating the average speed of the last 5 seconds... or is there something that I'm not factoring in here? (bear in mind that I may reduce the interval time to 1/5th of a second, and take 5 readings a second, theoretically being able to update the speed 5 times a second...or would this have detrimental effects)

Any feed back would be GREATLY appreciated!

//UPDATE 1. TAKEN FROM MY POST ON [THE ANDDEV FORUMS](http://www.anddev.org/post99851.html#p99851)

OK, so now I have a bit of an update for you.

The code has been significantly changed. I have devided it up into seperate class files.

The program now runs and gets it's current position, but dispite how long I wait, or move, or move and wait, it does not update. Now I know that this is probably just me doing something wrong but it's my understanding that the values provided in this line (highlighted in red) that determine the update frequency, amirite??

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1000, locationListener);

the main

GPSMain.java

Code:

```
package Hartford.gps;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GPSMain extends Activity {

   //text views to display latitude and longitude
   TextView latituteField;
   TextView longitudeField;
   TextView currentSpeedField;

   protected double lat;
   protected double lon;

   //object to store previous location data
   protected Location oldLocation = null;

   //object to define 2 minutes of time
   static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;

   //object to store value for current speed
   protected int currentSpeed = 0;

   //boolean value used to compare new location with previous location
   protected boolean betterLocation;

   //list of locations to be used when calculating currentSpeed
   private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();   

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      run();

   }

   private void run(){
      //Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
      LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

      // Define a listener that responds to location updates
      LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

         public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

            //temporarily store newLocation
            oldLocation = newLocation;

            //add the newLocation to the list
            locations = Calculations.updateLocations(locations, newLocation);
            currentSpeed = Calculations.calculateSpeed(locations, currentSpeed);

            lat = (double) (newLocation.getLatitude());
            lon = (double) (newLocation.getLongitude());

            latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
            longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);
            currentSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);

            latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
            longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lon));
            currentSpeedField.setText(String.valueOf(currentSpeed));

         }

         //not entirely sure what these do yet
         public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
         public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
         public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

      };

      // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates every second or kilometer
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1000, locationListener);
   }

}
```

the calculations class

Calculations.java

Code:

```
package Hartford.gps;

import java.util.List;

import android.location.Location;

public class Calculations {

   //update the locations list
   static List <Location> updateLocations(List <Location> locations, Location newLocation){

      List<Location> updatedLocations = locations;

      //create buffer
      Location buff = null;

      //if there are already 5 elements in the array
      if (updatedLocations.size()==5) {

         //remove the oldest location from the list and shift the remaining 4 down
         int i;
         //loop that executes 5 times
         for(i = 0; i > 4; i++){

            //store the value of the "i"th value in the array
            buff = updatedLocations.get(i+1);

            //replace the "i"th value with the "i-1"th
            //(effectively push the last element off and move the rest up)
            updatedLocations.set(i, buff);
         }

         //add the newest location to the beginning of the list
         updatedLocations.set(i, newLocation);

      //if there are less than 5 elements already in the array
      }else{

         //just add the newest location to the end
         updatedLocations.add(newLocation);

      }
      return updatedLocations;

   }



   //method to calculate speed

   //NB: I KNOW THAT THIS METHOD DOES NOT CURRENTLY CALCULATE THE CORRECT SPEED!
   //    I JUST HAVE IT DOING ADDITION SO THAT WHEN I'M DEBUGING THAT I CAN TELL IF IT IS
   //    WORKING OR NOT

   static int calculateSpeed(List<Location> locations, int speed){

      List <Location> speedList = locations;

      int totalSpeed = speed;

      while(speedList.contains(true)){

         totalSpeed++;

      }

      return totalSpeed;
   }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package Hartford.gps;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GPSMain extends Activity implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

//text views to display latitude and longitude
TextView latituteField;
TextView longitudeField;
TextView currentSpeedField;
TextView kmphSpeedField;
TextView avgSpeedField;
TextView avgKmphField;

//objects to store positional information
protected double lat;
protected double lon;

//objects to store values for current and average speed
protected double currentSpeed;
protected double kmphSpeed;
protected double avgSpeed;
protected double avgKmph;
protected double totalSpeed;
protected double totalKmph;

//counter that is incremented every time a new position is received, used to calculate average speed
int counter = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    run();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    super.onPause();
}

private void run(){

    final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    //Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

            counter++;

            //current speed fo the gps device
            currentSpeed = round(newLocation.getSpeed(),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            kmphSpeed = round((currentSpeed*3.6),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            //all speeds added together
            totalSpeed = totalSpeed + currentSpeed;
            totalKmph = totalKmph + kmphSpeed;

            //calculates average speed
            avgSpeed = round(totalSpeed/counter,3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            avgKmph = round(totalKmph/counter,3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            //gets position
            lat = round(((double) (newLocation.getLatitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            lon = round(((double) (newLocation.getLongitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
            longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);             
            currentSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
            kmphSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kmph);
            avgSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.avgspeed);
            avgKmphField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.avgkmph);

            latituteField.setText("Current Latitude:        "+String.valueOf(lat));
            longitudeField.setText("Current Longitude:      "+String.valueOf(lon));
            currentSpeedField.setText("Current Speed (m/s):     "+String.valueOf(currentSpeed));
            kmphSpeedField.setText("Cuttent Speed (kmph):       "+String.valueOf(kmphSpeed));
            avgSpeedField.setText("Average Speed (m/s):     "+String.valueOf(avgSpeed));
            avgKmphField.setText("Average Speed (kmph):     "+String.valueOf(avgKmph));

        }

        //not entirely sure what these do yet
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, locationListener);
}

//Method to round the doubles to a max of 3 decimal places
public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode)
{
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
    BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
    return rounded.doubleValue();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```